# Is it possible to have my account frozen?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I know this sounds really weird, but I don't want access to my Stack Exchange account for a while, but I would like to keep it to use in the future. Is it possible for the SE team to freeze my account?

It is like this: I like SE. I am beginning to feel I like it a bit too much. In order to make sure that participating on SE does not have a negative impact on other priorities, I have decided to put my activity on hold. This brings me to a position in which it is a choice between having my account frozen somehow, or deleting it. I *really* don't want to delete my account, as I have just made it over 2k rep; I would lose all of my rep, badges and privileges, and have to start all over again from scratch.

That brings me back to the question: Is there any way possible to have my account locked or frozen?

Comment: AFAIK, the closest you get is a ban. And the SE team/mods isn't going to ban the account over that. If you want to not access the network, you could use a plugin for your browser that blocks the website

Comment: As a mod - my typical response is - well, we're not your parents or your sense of self control. Someone I know actually got a friend to change his password, seal it up and left it somewhere in case he wanted to come back. Might be a solution here.

Comment: Thanks @servy I thought there was something like that, but _I could not find it_. Anyway, I leave this here, it might be easier to find for someone else.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You should add that as an answer to the duplicate post. That a lot better idea/answer than the ones already there — the ones suggesting the misuse of a punitive feature for this purpose.

Comment: Added it - with some changes to the master of the master of this, which feels like a different question.